# How to find Rate and Order of Convergence of Fixed Point Method

Tags: functions, numerical-methods, roots, approximation

Given the function $f(x) = (e^x - 1)^2$, we can use a fixed-point iteration to approximate the root.

$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{(e^{x_n} - 1)^2}{2e^{x_n}(e^{x_n}-1)}$$

This gives the following iterations after an initial guess $x_0 = 1$:

$$x_1 = 0.6839$$ $$x_2 = 0.4363$$ $$x_3 = 0.2595$$$$x_4=0.1452$$ And so on. The error $E$ for each iteration is just the value of the iteration itself, given that the exact solution is $0$. My question is: How does one find both the rate and order of convergence, given these iterations? Is there a specific formula or does one try to find a pattern from the ratio of consecutive errors? Then, can you prove these claims using Taylor series about the root? Any explanations would be brilliant.

Comment: Imagine that $x_n$ is quite close to the root, so here is quite small.  Find an expression for the leading order term for $x_{n+1}$.  You can use Taylor series for the pieces of your iteration, keeping enough terms that they don't all cancel.  You should get something like $x_{n+1} \approx a x_n^b$.

Comment: So for this expression, is it essentially just trial-and-error to find an appropriate coefficient and power?

Comment: No, you replace $e^{x_n}$ with $1+x_n +\frac 12x_n^2$ and so on in in the formula and derive the leading term for $x_{n+1}$.  It is not trial and error.  I find you should get $x_{n+1} \approx \frac 12x_n$ for $x_n$ small, so the convergence is linear.

Comment: I meant in terms for finding the rate of convergence, i.e. the coefficient of the ratio of errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sequence is converging with order $p$, you have that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{|z-x_{n+1}|}{|z-x_n|^p} = K_{\infty}^{[p]}
$$

Imagining that $n$ is large enough (and using $z=0$), you would expect $|x_{n+1}| \approx K |x_n|^p$. In particular,
$$
\frac{|x_{n+1}|}{|x_n|} \approx \frac{K|x_n|^p}{K|x_{n-1}|^p} = \left(\frac{|x_n|}{|x_{n-1}|}\right)^p.
$$

From this relation you can estimate
$$
p = \frac{\log(|x_{n+1}|/|x_n|)}{\log(|x_n|/|x_{n-1}|)}
$$

In this situation, we have

$$
p \approx \frac{\log(|x_4/x_3|))}{\log(|x_3/x_2|)}\approx 1.17
$$

which suggests linear convergence, as expected.

---

We could have guessed this right from the start... The iteration process is $x_{n+1}= \underbrace{x_n+\frac 12 e^{-x_n}-\frac 12}_{g(x_n)}$
Using Taylor's formula you get

\begin{align*}
|x_{n+1} - z| = & |g(x_n)-z|=|g(z) + g'(\xi)(x_n -z)|, \xi \in (z,x_n)\\
= & |g'(\xi)| |x_n-z|
\end{align*}

So, when $x_n$ is close to $z$, the constant in front of $|x_n-z|$ is close to $|g'(0)| = \frac 12$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So you're saying this sequence coverges linearly, i.e. order 1, but what about the rate of convergence? Is it possible to demonstrate this assertion by writing a Taylor series for $x_{n+1}$?

Comment: @Semmah Once we have established linear convergence, we know that $|x_{n+1}| \leq C |x_n|$ for some $0 \leq C < 1$. So, this constant $C$ can now be estimated by computing the ratio of consecutive iterations: $\frac|{x_3|}{|x_2|} \approx 0.59$,  $\frac|{x_4|}{|x_3|} \approx 0.56, \cdots$. So, the error drops more or less as $2^{-n}$.